# Drop rows depending on conditions in two or more columns

Tags: dataframe, iteration, drop

I am new at programming so forgive me ignorance.

I have the following dataframe:

```
          ID      Name    
0       AJ-6      Mark    
1       AJ-6      Mark     
2    AJ-6-FR    Judith    
3    AJ-6-FR    Judith  
4    AJ-6-FR Christian    
..       ...       ...   
299   TV-552     Marie   
300   TV-552      Ruth     
309  ZS-V-21      John     
310  ZS-V-21      John     
311  ZS-V-21      John
```

My intention is to drop those rows where the ID is repeated (i.e. rows 0 - 1 or 309-311) AND the same name is in the row.

I tried many things such as using iterrows and conditions with shifted columns but I am afraid it's not possible to drop multiple rows while iterating.

I am just showing two columns where conditions can be found, but there could be more (i.e. if column ['age'] >= 20: drop rows).

Thanks for your help Sirs and Madams.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df = df.loc[(df['ID']!=df['shiftdown'])&(df['ID']!=df['shiftup'])]
```

It check and keep rows only if the ID value is different from shiftdown and shiftup.

If instead you just want to drop rows with same values based on a specific column you can use df.drop_values(by=[col_name]), it is not clear from the question.

Comment: Dear Edoardo. Thank you very much for your input. I tried to apply your solution to my problem but I realized my problem is a bit more complex than I expected. I finally decided to reformulate it. Sorry for the inconvenience. I hope you can till help me.

Comment: I think that if you have multiple conditions to apply which are really different from each other, it might be simpler to perform more 'cleaning' steps rather than condensing everything in a single line of code. Think about what priority to give to each condition (do you want to filter first by age or first check for duplicates?). Also, take a look at the lin k below, it contains code examples that you can replicate for your code. Without knowing exactly what you're output should look like it's hard to help more than this https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (if `df` is your DataFrame):

```
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['ID', 'Name'], inplace = True)
```